# Understanding void functions

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program named program52.py that uses main and a void function named numbers that takes no arguments and does not return anything. The numbers function generates 5 random integers, each greater than 10 and less than 30 (duplicates are okay), and prints them all on one line separated by spaces. A loop is required for this, and the loop should also total up the integers so the sum can be displayed when the loop ends. The main function should call the numbers function.

This is the requirements for them, I'm very new and I've had a great deal of trouble using void functions so as you might imagine this has been difficult. I was wondering if anyone had insight on how to do this, I would not like the solution I want to understand how to do it properly.

Comment: "void functions" aren't a thing in python, python functions don't have types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you don't need to define something to return for your function. It is by default void unless you add a return statement.
Refer to these for how to make functions:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp, https://realpython.com/python-main-function/

Additionnal sources to help in your work:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp,
https://www.techbeamers.com/python-random-number-tutorial/

You can quickly find answers to this type of question by looking it up on many websites like: W3Schools, GeeksForGeeks, RealPython and many others.